# FosRestBundle PATCH action + entity field with NotBlank constraint

Tags: php, symfony, fosrestbundle

I have a `Dns` entity who have a `content` field with a `NotBlank` constraint

```
/**
 * @var int
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
 * @Assert\Regex("/^(([[:alnum:]-_]+(\.[[:alnum:]-_]+)*)|(\*))$/u")
 */
private $name;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="content", type="string", length=64000, nullable=true)
 * @Assert\NotBlank
 * @Assert\Length(max="64000")
 */
private $content;
```

I have made a working `PATCH` action with [FosRestBundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSRestBundle)

```
/**
 * @ParamConverter("updatedRecord", converter="fos_rest.request_body")
 */
public function patchAction(PowerDNSDomain $domain, PowerDNSRecord $record, PowerDNSRecord $updatedRecord, ConstraintViolationListInterface $validationErrors)
{
    if ($validationErrors->count() > 0) {
        return $this->handleBodyValidationErrorsView($validationErrors);
    }

    $record->setName($updatedRecord->getName())
           ->setContent($updatedRecord->getContent())
           ->setTtl($updatedRecord->getTtl())
           ->setPrio($updatedRecord->getPrio());

    $this->get('manager.dns')->saveRecord($record);

    return $this->view($record);
}
```

When I'm trying to update a `Dns` entry without changing the `content` field i get the following error because of my `NotBlank` constraint.

> {
>     "error": "validation_failed",
>     "error_description": "Data validation failed. Please check errors below.",
>     "validation_errors": {
>       "content": [
>         "This value cannot be null."
>       ]
>     }
>   }

This is doing the same with `NotNull` constraint.

I'm trying to PATCH a `Dns` entry without changing the `content` field.

Is this possible to keep my constraint inside the entity  or I must use another way ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can deal with [validation groups](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/validation.html#validation-groups) to keep your constraint on `INSERT` and skip it on `UPDATE`.

Example:

```
/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="content", type="string", length=64000, nullable=true)
 * @Assert\NotBlank(groups={"new"})
 * @Assert\Length(max="64000")
 */
private $content;
```

Then, if your method is creating a new entry, set the `new` validation group in the `@ParamConverter` annotation:

```
/**
 * @ParamConverter("updatedRecord", converter="fos_rest.request_body", options={"validator"={"groups"={"new"}}})
 */
```

See the [Request body listener](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/FOSRestBundle/request_body_converter_listener.html) for more.